# Using validation Rule in salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I have one text filed, when i am not fill the text field, display one default value.

using validation rule.

Thanks
kumar

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear.

If you want to prevent saving the record if the value is not filled in - the easiest way is to mark the field as required (on the field itself or on the page layout). If it really has to be done with a validation rule - `ISBLANK(TextField__c)`.

If you want to provide default value - again, easiest is to set is as default on the field itself.

If you want to have something like "user didn't fill anything and he's saving the record, I need to overwrite it before save actually happens" - best way would be a workflow rule. Same condition as the one written above, action = field update

Comment: Hi eyescream, I kneed only using for validation rule. for displaying defult value.

Comment: Validation rules block saving of the record :) Only thing they can display is an error message. If you really wan't to show such error: "You didn't fill this field, please write something there, even 'Default value'" then it's a bad user interface experience and a workflow that silently fills it in or default value on the field itself would be much better...

Comment: Hi eyescream, I have Two Fields(FirstName,LastName) Using triggers I want add both(FirstName+LastName) in a single field in Middle Name.

Comment: This looks like a new question. Plus StackOverflow is more for solving problems and not doing your homework or something. If you have a problem with your current trigger code - post it. But the community here won't like simple "solve this assignment for me". And why triggers, that's a task that can be done in simpler ways.